# New Facebook Pages Created Every Time OG type is Video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

So, we often create posts with videos in them and mark up the page using Open graph so that it will be shared on walls with the video inline.

In order to do so, we also have to set og:type to video, so that Facebook will allow that video to play.

However, it seems that every time that URL is liked/shared/etc..., it automatically creates a new Facebook page for that entry.  For example - https://www.facebook.com/pages/Checklist-For-Upgrading-Your-YouTube-Channel-The-Reel-Web-Episode-29/255041577914205

Because we do a lot of this, we have hundreds of new pages on Facebook...  Is there a way to share video but not have it create a new page each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.

These 'pages' are not visible to the users, and are only visible to you as admins. They exist to allow you to publish content to the users who have liked your Page.

This happens for all URLs which are 'liked' - not just those with og:video set in the markup.

Comment: Thanks.  That's interesting and I didn't realize they were just for admins. Not sure I understand the benefit myself but glad you could answer.  I will say though - it doesn't happen with og=article.